# Error in sending pdfkit doc from node.js to client

Tags: node.js, strapi, pdfkit

I am trying to send a pdf file generated using pdfkit in node.js to the client.

If my pdf contains any image, then my code will give the following error. Otherwise (without any image), this code will work without errors

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

This is my code

```
var doc = new PDFDocument({
              bufferPages: true,
            }),
    svg = mySvg;

SVGtoPDF(doc, svg, 0, 0);
let buffers = [];

doc.on("data", buffers.push.bind(buffers));
doc.on("end", () => {
    let pdfData = Buffer.concat(buffers);
    ctx.res
    .writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(pdfData),
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
        "Content-disposition": "attachment;filename=file.pdf",
    })
    .end(pdfData);
});
doc.end();
```

I am using strapi as my backend framework.
When I tried to write the file to the server, then it will work fine. But I need to send the file without storing in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in **doc.pipe(ctx.res)**. Try to add after **.end(pdfData)**

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${fileName}`,
});

doc.pipe(ctx.res);
doc.end();
```

For me it works fine, but after 3-4 downloads response is a timed out. Moved ***doc.on("data", buffers.push.bind(buffers));*** at the start doc

```
let buffers = [];
doc.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));

/* doc body here */
doc.text('pdf');
doc.text('pdf2');
doc.text('pdf3');

doc.on('end', () => {
    const pdfData = Buffer.concat(buffers);
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(pdfData),
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
      'Content-disposition': `attachment; filename=${filename}.pdf`,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }).end(pdfData);
  });

doc.end();
```